# python:[WinError 267] The directory name is invalid

Tags: python, anaconda

i was opening sample dicom files but i got this error 
[WinError 267] The directory name is invalid

I am using anaconda, pydicom 1.1.0 aIf anyone can help me with this, or even just help me how to load a DICOM file in general, I would appreciate it a lot.

```
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
import pydicom
import os
import scipy.ndimage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import measure, morphology
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection

# Some constants 
data_dir ="F:\\deep\\sample\\"
patients = os.listdir(data_dir)

for patient in patients[:1]:
    path = data_dir + patient
    slices = [dicom.read_file(path + '/' + s) for s in os.listdir(path)]
    slices.sort(key = lambda x: int(x.ImagePositionPatient[2]))
#the first slice
plt.imshow(slices[0].pixel_array)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The backslash (`\`) character is used to escape the character after it. If you want to have an actual `\` in your path, you'll have to escape it by doubling it (i.e., `\\`):

```
data_dir ="F:\\deep\\sample\\"
# Here -------^-----^
```

Comment: i made this but the error is the same

Comment: have you got any solution. I'm facing same here